# df -k + how to match the root volume line

Tags: linux, sed, awk, grep, perl

How to match the "/" volume from `df -k` command?

I  tried the following:

```
[root@machine /]# df -k | grep "/"
/dev/vx/dsk/bootdg/rootvol 130926685 71378710 58238709    56%    /
/devices                   0       0       0     0%    /devices
ctfs                       0       0       0     0%    /system/contract
proc                       0       0       0     0%    /proc
mnttab                     0       0       0     0%    /etc/mnttab
   .
   .
```

.

```
df -k | grep " / "       ( no any output )
```

.

```
df -k | grep " \/ "      ( no any output )
```

the requested output:

```
/dev/vx/dsk/bootdg/rootvol 130926685 71378710 58238709    56%    /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df -k | grep '/$'
```

or you can use `awk`:

```
df -k | awk '$NF == "/"'
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you directly give `/` as parameter to `df -k`?

```
df -k / | tail -n +2
```

This will give the list without the header.

Comment: This should be the top answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to say ' /$' you can use the sets name for space too, i.e. `[[:space:]]`.

Example:

```
$ df -k | grep '[[:space:]]/$'
/dev/mapper/fedora_greeneggs-root  51475068  24631544  24205700  51% /
```

If you do testing though, you'll notice that inclusion of the space is unnecessary since `/` is the only entry in the output that is terminated by the EOL (End of Line). So you can leverage this fact like this:

```
$ df -k | grep '/$'
/dev/mapper/fedora_greeneggs-root  51475068  24631552  24205692  51% /
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep -E` which allows search by regular expressions. As `/` is on the end of the line you can add end-of-the-line symbol `$`:

```
df -k | grep -E "/$"
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the following command grep on the unique word in the line:

```
$ df -kh | grep "rootvol"
```